# Format date that is dynamically added to text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, formatting

I have a table containing details for a series of invoices where the date is currently output like this after being fetched from an array of objects:

```
2017-03-20T00:00:00
```

How can I format the values for each date output to match the dd mm yyyy date format?

Tried using the following code with the datepicker plugin but I'm not familiar with it and don't think I've been using it correctly.

```
$('.invoiceDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy'
})
```

Comment: There is a sample : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#startdate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" }).val()
```